# Geolocation: detect changes

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am currently developing an app with Ionic 2/Cordova and I'm trying to find a way to watch (update) the user position if e.g. it changes with a fixed minimum distance (30 meters).

I already tried:

- getCurrentPosition() but I just get the user position one time
- watchPosition() but It gets called too frequently (around 15 times per minute even if I don't move the phone)
- mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation that has the option *distanceFilter* but It also tracks the user position in the background and I don't need it

Any suggestion?

Comment: How would the app know if the user has moved 30 meters. Best solution would be to use $interval in angular js with an interval of 6000 miliseconds to get current position, considering that the user might move by 30 meters in a minute

Comment: Or to use any plugin that uses locationmanager's [requestlocationupdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates) in a way so that you can pass minDistance(third parameter) into this method. this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation) accepts such parameter for instance. You can also stop this plugin by listening on the pause event that is triggered when an app is put into background.